# While creating a cordova app error is powershell is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: powershell, cordova

So I am creating a cordova app using the command is `cordova create TestApp` and the error is
Command failed: powershell (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).caption
'powershell' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. I have also attached the screenshot please take a look at this.
[image]

Comment: Please, don't show screenshot of console, because it is hard to read. Select the text using the mouse, then copy the text by pressing the right mouse button. Insert it in your question as preformatted text, like `<pre>The Text</pre>`.

Comment: So the error is Command failed: powershell (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).caption 'powershell' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

First you should excute the command "powershell"，

If fail, config system variable path `"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0"`.

If your windows System32 folder have no WindowsPowerShell this folder, install powershell and config it to system variable path